# !address -summary command output for latest Windbg/SOS

Tags: .net-4.0, windbg, sos

I downloaded and installed the latest version (6.12.2.633) of Debugging tools for windows. Running it with .NET 4.0. When I run `!address -summary` command seem like its output is different than what I used to see with previous version of Windbg/SOS for .NET 3.5. Anyone knows where can I find document for latest `!address -summary` command. SOS build-in help is not very helpful

Comment: `!address` is not a SOS command, so obviously the help file for SOS will be of no help. Did you check the help file for WinDbg?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Your channcel 9 Advanced .NET Debugging Part 1 video, there is a slide (at 0:28 minute) that states ! is an extension command. Based on that my understanding for !address also is that its an extension dll command?

Comment: Windbg can load several extensions. SOS is one of them. !address is a command of Ext.dll extension. You can see all loaded extensions with .chain

Comment: @imak. That's correct. Extension commands start with !, but as plodoc says there are many different extensions each with their own set of commands. SOS help only covers the extensions implemented in sos.dll.

Comment: thanks guys for comments. I guess I was consfused with use of ! to be a sos command. Now I don't know how to mark this one as answered as everyone is commenting on my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!address` is a native extension command that is always available during user mode or kernel mode debugging. It displays information about the memory of the target application or computer. See also the [documentation for this command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561519(v=VS.85).aspx).

It is possible to have multiple extensions loaded in WinDbg. You can use the `.chain` command to list the loaded extensions.

SOS is an extension dedicated to .NET debugging. It comes with its own set of commands to analyse memory used by managed applications, e.g. `!eeheap -gc`.